# Get Child category "name" of post

Tags: categories

I have this piece of ode in a buy template. I like to know what to add to get the child name of the category

the mais display category is sponsor. but in the sponsor category, there is : gold, silver, platium... i want to get that "color" category an output it as `<div class="cat-name">platium</div>`

here is the code :

```
<div id="carouselContainer">
<h2 id="sponsorsTitle"><?php echo get_cat_name( $carouselCategory ) ?></h2>
<ul id="carousel">
    <?php $showPostsInCategory = new WP_Query(); $showPostsInCategory->query('cat='. $carouselCategory .'&showposts='. $carouselNumber .'');
    if ($showPostsInCategory->have_posts()) : while ($showPostsInCategory->have_posts()) : $showPostsInCategory->the_post();?>
        <li>
            <?php $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true ); ?>
            <?php echo get_cat_name( $carouselCategory ) ?>
            <a href="<?php  if ($data[ 'custom_link' ]) { echo $data[ 'custom_link' ];} else { the_permalink(); } ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('sponsor', array('title' => "")); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul><!--end carousel-->
</div><!--end carouselContainer-->
<?php } ?>

<div id="footerContainer">
<div id="footer">
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`wp_get_post_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories)? I'm not sure what you're trying to get the child category of, as you are querying posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

menardmam, this is my solution:

```
    <?php $showPostsInCategory = new WP_Query(); $showPostsInCategory->query('cat='. $carouselCategory .'&showposts='. $carouselNumber .'');
     if ($showPostsInCategory->have_posts()) :  while ($showPostsInCategory->have_posts()) : $showPostsInCategory->the_post(); ?>
      <li>
           <?php $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true ); ?>
           <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {echo ( $category->cat_name != $carouselCategory ) ? $category->cat_name . ' ' : '';}?>
           <a href="<?php  if ($data[ 'custom_link' ]) { echo $data[ 'custom_link' ];} else { the_permalink(); } ?>">
           <?php the_post_thumbnail('sponsor', array('title' => "")); ?>
           </a>
      </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The `get_the_category` retrieves every category (parent and child) of your post, but by using the `$category->cat_name != $carouselCategory` part the parent category won't be displayed, just the child.

Comment: this is just perfect... but i have found a solution myself... i will get you my solution, but mark you as the approved answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function get_me_the_child_cat($arr, $val){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    if ($arr[$key] == $val){
    unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    }
    $arr_clean = array_values($arr);
    return (get_cat_name( $arr_clean[0]));
}
?>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--end content-->
</div><!--end contentContainer-->


<div id="carouselContainer">
<h2 id="sponsorsTitle"><?php echo get_cat_name( $carouselCategory ) ?></h2>
<div id="carousel">
<ul>
    <?php $showPostsInCategory = new WP_Query(); $showPostsInCategory->query('cat='. $carouselCategory .'&showposts='. $carouselNumber .'');
    if ($showPostsInCategory->have_posts()) : while ($showPostsInCategory->have_posts()) : $showPostsInCategory->the_post();?>
        <li class="spacerli">
            <?php $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true ); ?>
            <div class="headerlogo"><?php $all_cat = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID); echo (get_me_the_child_cat($all_cat,$carouselCategory));?></div>
            <a href="<?php  if ($data[ 'custom_link' ]) { echo $data[ 'custom_link' ];} else { the_permalink(); } ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('sponsor', array('title' => "")); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```